# PowerApp not mapping values into Azure DevOps integration correctly

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I created a Microsoft Powerapp application which has three fields: name, companyororganization and score. These values should be sent to Azure Devops, so I created Azure DevOps integration in PowerApps (there is ready build integration for that).

Name is mapped into title, score is mapped into Createworkitem_Userenteredfields and company is mapped into Createworkitem_userenterfields_1.

In Powerapps i'm calling the service with code:
PowerAppsbutton.Run({Score: 100}, "Example name", {Companyororganization: "abc"}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})

*Empty fields are there because I have created 6 dynamic contents into flow and don't know how to delete extra ones...*

Code gives me following exception in Flow:
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: 'workItem' missing for requested operation: 'CreateWorkItem'.\r\nclientRequestId: a5353fe7-59c7-474f-a05f-6a6407d61c80",
  "source": "vsts-we.azconn-we.p.azurewebsites.net"
}

Here is image of request. For some reason the Companyoroganization, score and name are all unmapped. Is this bug in Azure DevOps connector?

[image]